# Bug in VBA in MSProject how to check if sub project is loaded in master project?

Tags: vba, macros, ms-project

If I place watch on the `tmp` variable and stop on the line `If Not tmp Then` both show up as true, I.e. `tmp` is True and `Not tmp` is True.

```
Dim subProj As Subproject
For Each subProj In prj.Subprojects
    Dim tmp As Boolean
    tmp = subProj.IsLoaded
    If Not tmp Then
        ExportTaskToExcel subProj.SourceProject, StartDate, EndDate
    End If
Next
```

What should I do to check if the subproject is not loaded (not expanded) in master project?

[Look at image under this link which is showing that in the same time: True = not True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3A4B.png)

Comment: You should type all relevant code into your question as opposed to an image of it, but supporting images can always be helpful

Comment: Proposed resolution didnt work earlier. When I was seeking why, Ive found this bug. So sorry but Your advice is not enough.

Comment: Your issue was with a boolean showing true and true due to `IsBoolean` being used. Can you post a link to the bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you have tmp declared somewhere else that can be seen from here causing this issue (i.e. it is declared public in another module). Try changing the name to isolate it, also, I've never declared a variable in a loop before, While I'm not sure of the implications, I would not recommend it.

```
Dim subProj As Subproject
Dim tmp10 As Boolean
For Each subProj In prj.Subprojects
    tmp10 = subProj.IsLoaded
    If Not tmp10 Then
        ExportTaskToExcel subProj.SourceProject, StartDate, EndDate
    End If
Next
```

You may have done it for a specific reason but you could omit the variable altogether: -

```
Dim subProj As Subproject
For Each subProj In prj.Subprojects
    If Not subProj.IsLoaded Then
        ExportTaskToExcel subProj.SourceProject, StartDate, EndDate
    End If
Next
```